# Cypress | Is there a way to test the tests we have written

Tags: cypress

I'm wanting to test our tests that we have written. For example, if a developer creates a test with the type command, for example:

```
cy.get('input').type('Hello, World')
```

I want to test if this **type()** has the option of **log:false**. If there is no option of **log:false** then fail the test.

Code should look like this:

```
cy.get('input').type('Hello, World', { log: false })
```

Has anyone using Cypress accomplished this? Running tests to test our tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite what you asked, but

**/cypress/support/index.js**

```js
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('type', (originalFn, text, options) => {

  // enforce no-log policy
  return originalFn(text, { ...options, log: false })
})
```

Or if you like to finger-wag

```js
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('type', (originalFn, text, options) => {

  if (!options.log || options.log) {
    throw "  No logging allowed on .type()"
  }

  return originalFn(text, options)
})
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is perfect. I did not know you could over-ride the cypress function's. 
I've completed the action like so:
`if (options.log === true || options.log === undefined) {`

Meaning that if the logging is undefined or true, it'll ping the developer that this needs to change to false. Thank you for helping out!

Comment: Yeah, I got the if logic a bit wrong. Keep in mind `!option.log` will catch explicit `{ log: false }`  settings, but that's unlikely to be used?